# Issue converting from series to str on python 2.7.4 Anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, data-cleaning

```
import sys
sys.version
```

> '2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2014, 15:12:11) [MSC
>   v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'

```
from pandas import DataFrame,Series
import datetime

id = [199995,199996,199997]
hour = [14102101,14102102,14102103]
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':Series(id),'hour':Series(hour)})
kk=df.hour.apply(str)
df_dt=datetime.datetime.strptime(kk,"%y%m%d%H").date()
```

> TypeError: must be string, not Series

I got this data from a time dimension table off a relational database so I cant really do much to change the importing format. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in `kk` to your `strptime(...)` which is a series where it is expecting a string. You can iterate over the rows in the series if you wish to print out each of the dates like so:

```
for i in range(len(kk)):
    df_dt=datetime.datetime.strptime(kk[i],"%y%m%d%H")
    print(df_dt)
```

which will give you

```
2014-10-21 01:00:00
2014-10-21 02:00:00
2014-10-21 03:00:00
2014-10-21 03:00:00
```

However, I am guessing at what your desired output is since you did not specify that in your original question.

## edit

Using the `%timeit` module running in IPython Notebook the `for` loop compared to the `apply.(lambda ...)` is a little over 3 times as fast.

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 91.6 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 345 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thx so much for the help. but I try to not use for loop.

Comment: @kayama is there a reason you don't want to use a loop? According to the `%timeit` module running in IPython Notebook, the for loop implementation is over 3 times as fast as a lambda apply.

Comment: I thought the for loop is less efficient as l thought the dataframe apply is optimized for matrix type operation like MATLAB. I probably use your approach and stitch the result back to the main dataframe. What's is the most efficient to stitch that column vector back to the data frame

Comment: @kayama If by stitch you mean append the column back to the original data frame then you can do something like `original_df['new_column'] = df_dt` assuming your `df_dt` data frame is a nx1 column vector.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['hour_dt']=df.hour.apply(lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x.astype(str),"%y%m%d%H") )
```